# Train_test_split set with 50-50 returns high accuracy but low when separated in 2 files

Tags: python-3.x, random-forest, train-test-split

I have 1 dataset (called **train_plus_test.csv**) that has 1275 rows with corresponding columns and labels for classification of two activities, namely Walking and Lying. This is a balanced dataset with same number of each class.

I implement Random Forest in 2 scenarios

Scenario 1: Training on **train_plus_test.csv** with the train-test split of 0.75 - 0.25, it gives 91.8% accuracy

Scenario 2: Divide the above file **train_plus_test.csv** into 2 files (**training.csv**) and testing (**testing.csv**) at the split of 75% - 25%. Then I train the model on **train.csv** and predict on **test.csv**, but the accuracy is 52%. I am Now wondering where exactly I am wrong? @@

Thank you for your reading!

The python code (below) and 3 csv files above I have included here:

[GoogleDrive] https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AAOOFhR1QpoPPtSNTofBnouBaYHfFbir?usp=sharing&fbclid=IwAR10SjHCu-6Sszd-okes-IneAA8pWzals9-NNtAsmrw0ql28mk3geZfmnQI

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

# Scenario 1 ==================>
dataset = pd.read_csv('train_plus_test.csv')
feature_cols = list(dataset.columns.values)
feature_cols.remove('label')
X = dataset[feature_cols] # Features
y = dataset['label'] # Target

clf_RF = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=0, max_features=8, min_samples_leaf=3)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)
clf_RF.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred_RF = clf_RF.predict(X_test)
print('Accuracy of training')
print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred_RF))

# Scenario 2 ======= comment Secenario 1 before running the scenario 2 ===========>

train_dataset = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
test_dataset = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
feature_cols = list(train_dataset.columns.values)
feature_cols.remove('label')
clf_RF = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=0, max_features=8, min_samples_leaf=3 )
X = train_dataset[feature_cols] # Features
y = train_dataset['label'] # Target
clf_RF.fit(X, y)

X_test_data = test_dataset[feature_cols]
y_test_data = test_dataset['label']
y_test_pred = clf_RF.predict(X_test_data)
print('Accuracy of testing')
print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test_data, y_test_pred))
```

Comment: This might be of interest to you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/402391/why-the-performance-of-random-forest-is-related-to-the-order-of-training-samples, if you want the to be same export `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test` to their own csv in scenario 1, then run scenario 2 with those csv's

Comment: @BenPap I am just a beginner to this and not really understand much about those parameter setting. I just want to train the model and test the model on new instance. I dont know why the training accuracy is high but the testing is just too low they come from the same. Is this because of the model or because of the setting? Could you suggest me a clear solution for this? Thank you!

Comment: How have you randomized before splitting train and test files?

Comment: @Pen Pap, Davide ND. Thank you for your replies. I have learnt and fixed the issue based on you answers. Thank you!